# What are Shāstras’ view on people seeking to learn without adhikāra?

Tags: vedas, jnana

Though the traditional varnashrama dharma is on decline at present, there exists many curious souls who want to know the truth through self-study, many of whom are uninitiated through upanayana, vrātyas, varnashankara, Shudras or even mlecchas by birth. I’m not talking about just the Vedas but also other major texts there are e.g. Upanishads, puranas, Smritis, Bhagavad gita, works of  great rishis like adi shankaracharya . What do shāstras dictate on this matter.

Comment: There are many posts already on similar things please search for archives. If its allowed for vedas then other scriptures are no exceptions